# Visual Basic Express 2008 crashes upon opening

Tags: visual-studio

Everytime I open visual basic express 2008 it will just show the ide, once I click on something or after 3 to 5 seconds it will close without telling any error.

Comment: Tried to do this... but still no go..,C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vbexpress.exe /safemode

Comment: `Without telling any error` - Even in Event Logs?

Answer (score 0):

Check your system for any malware. Try reinstalling VStudio. Also try running VB after booting into safe mode. If nothing helps its better to reinstall windows.